# Unity Quiz Game displaying incorrect answers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a Quiz Game Multiple Choice by following the Official Tutorial in Unity on making a Quiz Game. I'm trying to display all the incorrect/wrong answers of the game how can I do it? Here is the code.

For Showing Questions

```
    void ShowQuestion()
{

    RemoveAnswerButtons();


    bool questionChosen = false;
    while (questionChosen != true) // While question chosen does not equal true
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, questionPool.Length); // Choose a random number between 0 and the questionPool length

        if (!questionIndexesChosen.Contains(random)) // If the new list doesn't contain the number
        {
            questionIndexesChosen.Add(random); // Add the number to the list
            questionIndex = random; // Set the questionIndex to the number
            questionChosen = true; // Set questionChosen to true to end the while loop
        }
    }

    QuestionData questionData = questionPool[questionIndex];                            // Get the QuestionData for the current question
    questionText.text = questionData.questionText;                                      // Update questionText with the correct text
```

For Questions----->Button

```
 for (int i = 0; i < questionData.answers.Length; i ++)                             // For every AnswerData in the current QuestionData...
    {
        GameObject answerButtonGameObject = answerButtonObjectPool.GetObject();         // Spawn an AnswerButton from the object pool
        answerButtonGameObjects.Add(answerButtonGameObject);
        answerButtonGameObject.transform.SetParent(answerButtonParent);
        answerButtonGameObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        AnswerButton answerButton = answerButtonGameObject.GetComponent<AnswerButton>();
        answerButton.SetUp(questionData.answers[i]);                                    // Pass the AnswerData to the AnswerButton so the AnswerButton knows what text to display and whether it is the correct answer
    }
}

void RemoveAnswerButtons()
{
    while (answerButtonGameObjects.Count > 0)                                           // Return all spawned AnswerButtons to the object pool
    {
        answerButtonObjectPool.ReturnObject(answerButtonGameObjects[0]);
        answerButtonGameObjects.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

And Answer Button Clicked and also to show the result if it was correct and wrong.

```
public void AnswerButtonClicked(bool isCorrect)
{
    if (isCorrect)
    {
        Debug.Log("Your Answer is Correct");
        playerScore += currentRoundData.pointsAddedForCorrectAnswer;                    // If the AnswerButton that was clicked was the correct answer, add points
        scoreDisplay.text = playerScore.ToString();

    }

    if (qNumber < questionPool.Length - 1)                                            // If there are more questions, show the next question
    {
        qNumber++;
        ShowQuestion();
    }
    else                                                                                // If there are no more questions, the round ends
    {
        EndRound();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Quiz Game, Highlight Button when Correct Answer is chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880008/unity-quiz-game-highlight-button-when-correct-answer-is-chosen)

Comment: It's the same question as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880008/unity-quiz-game-highlight-button-when-correct-answer-is-chosen

Comment: @Chopi I mean like Merriam Webster. which you will click the Review Results then all questions w/ answers will popup.

Comment: In that case you need to save the value which the player answered and the question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need the results screen, with the information. You can crate a gameobject called ResultsScren and it will have the childs with the results something similar to this

ResultsScreen <- This one has the ResultBehaviour script.

Result1 (ResultsScreen's child)

Reuslt2 (ResultsScreen's child)

Result3 (ResultsScreen's child)

You need something to store the questions and anwsers to finally show the results.

```
public List<bool> results = new List<bool>();// you can change this to something better like a Class that contains question ID, result, time used to response....
public void AnswerButtonClicked(bool isCorrect)
{
    results.Add(isCorrect); // the position in the array corresponts to the question. For example: Question 1 -> results[0]...Question2 -> results[1]
    if (isCorrect)
    {
        Debug.Log("Your Answer is Correct");
        playerScore += currentRoundData.pointsAddedForCorrectAnswer;                    // If the AnswerButton that was clicked was the correct answer, add points
        scoreDisplay.text = playerScore.ToString();

    }

    if (qNumber < questionPool.Length - 1)                                            // If there are more questions, show the next question
    {
        qNumber++;
        ShowQuestion();
    }
    else                                                                                // If there are no more questions, the round ends
    {
        EndRound();
    }
}
```

When you finish the round/game you have to draw your results, you have to ways for this:

- Instanciate a prefab for the UI and use the prefab (you need to place in the correct position).
- You can have a "hardcoded" screen with the positions and a array with the objects, this could be useful if the number of questions per game/round is always the same.

Script ResultsBehaviour:

```
public GameObject[] resultsItem; //Contains the UI GameObjects to print the results
public GameObject gameObjectWithScriptResults; // Attach the gameobject with the script "AnswerButtonClicked"
void OnEnable()
{
   ShowResults();
}
void ShowResults(){
   for(int i = 0;i < gameObjectWithScriptResults.getComponent<Script>.results.Count;i++) //this results are from where you have the other script
   {
       //Draw your result[i]
       resultsItem[i].GetComponent<Text>().text = gameObjectWithScriptResults.getComponent<Script>.results[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you finish the coding ? hehe trust me I've try hard so many times but because im still a beginner im having a hard time analyzing those codes.

Comment: Hi sir, can you help me go though this code. I'm really having a hard time on this, can you just give me the full code and I will just analyze it? thanks in advanced

Comment: 3 Questions sir, I'm getting a research of what you've said earlier... but can you help me right now? It sounds like I'm a newbie but I am really. Im just tring to make my game feasible.

Comment: @makemove can you take a look to my response now? I think it's almost done, you need to change very little

Comment: You have to put in ResultsBehaviour.resultsItem the 3 references to the UI items that will show the result. Right now will show true/false. I recommend you not to save the results in that script and use a Singleton with all the results.

Comment: No I will not save the results, all I want is for the user to see his/her Right and Wrong Answers

Comment: I will try it sir and if it does work I will let you know and so that I can give this question a Solved Question thanks !

Comment: You will have to initialize public GameObject[] resultsItem from the inspector just set the size of the array and drag the childrens to the array's rows

Comment: I'm just a little confused right now, will I create a another script to show the results?

Comment: Game mechanics and UI Control should be in different Scripts, you can share data between them using functions.   In your code you are controlling the collision (this should be done in your player script) + data + UI Control.

Comment: You should have a script just controlling the death status, and the show results in a different one.

Comment: Okay sir let me try it again.

Comment: So you mean I'll add another scene for it?

Comment: You don't need any other scene. Just another Script attached to you player. That script contains the OnCollisionEnter. When it collides it will enable the GameOver UI gameobject. This gameobject will get the data of your results.

Comment: This gameobject will get the data of your results from the player playerGameObject.getComponent<PlayerOnCollision>().results;

Comment: bro is this valid on a game with the data are on JSON?

Comment: why not?? of course it's valid, but using objects should be easier

Comment: So all I have to do is to create a new UI > Panel > Text ?? right? and disabled it ? .

Comment: So you mean the result screen is a text on the GUI?

Comment: You need to create a UI Panel and the texts that will show if the awnser was correct or not.

Sorry it's GetComponent<Script>(); https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/getcomponent

Comment: **public List<bool> results = new ArrayList<bool>();** is an error the **ArrayList** is an error .. any solutions on that?

Comment: public List<bool> results = new List<bool>();

Comment: One per each text you wanna show... but one question do you understand what are you coding with this?

Comment: No sir I don't :( sorry but i can't get it right. there's a lot of error