# Unity Quiz Game, Highlight Button when Correct Answer is chosen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to highlight the button into green when the correct answer is chosen how can I make that?

AnswerButton attached into the Script

```
public class AnswerButton : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Text answerText;

    private GameController gameController;
    private AnswerData answerData;

    void Start()
    {
        gameController = FindObjectOfType<GameController>();
    }

    public void SetUp(AnswerData data)
    {
        answerData = data;
        answerText.text = answerData.answerText;
    }

    public void HandleClick()
    {
        gameController.AnswerButtonClicked(answerData.isCorrect);
    }
}
```

My Game Controller which holds the button and Q n A

```
public void AnswerButtonClicked(bool isCorrect)
{
    if (isCorrect)
    {
        Debug.Log("Your Answer is Correct");
        playerScore += currentRoundData.pointsAddedForCorrectAnswer;
        // If the AnswerButton that was clicked was the correct answer, add points
        scoreDisplay.text = playerScore.ToString();

    }

    if (qNumber < questionPool.Length - 1)
    // If there are more questions, show the next question
    {
        qNumber++;
        ShowQuestion();
    }
    else
    // If there are no more questions, the round ends
    {
        EndRound();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need access to the button in the code, when the anwser is correct then change the background.

Keep in mind that you will have to "block" the screen while the button is green/correct color if not you will have the new question with the button with the background changed.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, something like this should work if you have an image on your button

```
GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
```

I've also seen code like this

```
    ColorBlock colors = GetComponent<Button> ().colors;
    colors.normalColor = Color.red;
    GetComponent<Button> ().colors = colors;
```

Note if the button is already colored, this will mix green into the existing color, so choose a neutral color for your button initially like white or light grey.